# Wordpress Categories Linking to Subcategories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm trying to accomplish a three-step page hierarchy in Wordpress.
Here's an example of what a breadcrumb navigation might look like:

> Mathematics > Algebra > Variables

I've got a page that lists all of my top-level categories:

> `<?php wp_list_categories('depth=1'); ?>`

What I need next is to make it so when you click a category, it links you to a page that *just lists all of its subcategories*. By default it takes you to a page with every post in that category.

So you could select say Math on the first page, followed by a page with sub-categories like Arithmetic, Algebra, Geometry, and then when you select your sub-cat it takes you to the posts.

I'm open to using any alternative methods too if you've any ideas on a better way to do it. Using the built-in category system just seemed most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

wp_list_categories can take an argument, 'child_of', that will return a list of child categories. So, in your individual category listing page, you can use the category id of the relevant category to retrieve the children like this:

```
<?php $children = wp_list_categories('child_of='.$your_category->cat_ID); ?>
```

Further documentation for wp_list_categories can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for unless I misunderstand its function. What I need is to have each category in the list *link* to a separate page with a list of its children. As far as displaying it all I'm having no issues, it's just a matter of anchoring.

Comment: In that case, what you need to do is edit category.php, (or the relevant category template), and use wp_list_categories to get a list of child categories to display within that template. Here's some information about category templates: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates